# How to Send Specific File From an number of file in telegram bot

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I wrote a telegram bot with C# that download file from user for example .docx file and convert this file to PDF.
I want after convert file to PDF,
return this file (PDF file) to user in between word file and PDF file.

This code return word file to user.

```
// Download File
Telegram.Bot.Types.File file = await bot.GetFileAsync(message.Document.FileId);
string fileName = file.FileId + "." + file.FilePath.Split('.').Last();

using (FileStream saveFileStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    await bot.DownloadFileAsync(file.FilePath, saveFileStream);
}
await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "File Saved");

// Convert Document to PDF
Spire.Doc.Document document = new Spire.Doc.Document();
document.LoadFromFile(fileName);
document.SaveToFile(fileName + ".pdf", Spire.Doc.FileFormat.PDF);

// Send PDF File
using (var sendFileStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
   await bot.SendDocumentAsync(chatId, new Telegram.Bot.Types.InputFiles.InputOnlineFile(sendFileStream, fileName));
}

await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "Your pdf file");
```

Comment: Please, What is the name of your libarary that convert from word to pdf?

Comment: I use Spire library